# Can I use ubuntu SSO with network.http.sendRefererHeader set to 0?

Tags: firefox, single-sign-on

I have just discovered that setting `network.http.sendRefererHeader` to `0` in firefox's `about:config` causes ubuntu-SSO to stop working, meaning I cannot log into any ubuntu-sso sites like launchpad or ask ubuntu.

Is there any way to use Ubuntu SSO without sending out https referers to every site I visit?